# Show $S_n/A_n$ is commutative

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, symmetric-groups, quotient-group

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group and $A_n$ the alternating subgroup. I want to show $S_n/A_n$ is commutative.

Given that the index of $A_n$ in $S_n$ is $2,$ the quotient group consists of two elements, $S_n/A_n = \{ A_n, \sigma A_n \mid \sigma \notin A_n\}.$ We want to show, $A_n \sigma A_n = \sigma A_n.$ This is equivalent to $(\sigma A_n)^2 = A_n,$ which is the well know condition of being abelian.

I thought first in terms of cycles. An element of $A_n$ is a product of an even number of $2-$cycles. Since $\sigma \notin A_n,$ it can be written as a product of an odd number of $2$-cycles.

Any suggestion how to go from here?

Thanks.

Comment: You a.ready know the quotient has two elements. Every group with two elements is abelian. What is the problem here?

Comment: For the same question see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4560262/quotient-group-s-n-a-n-is-abelian).

Comment: If $A_n$ is the identity element, then $A_n \sigma A_n=\sigma A_n=\sigma A_n A_n$, hence your group is abelian. If $\sigma A_n$ is the identity element, then $A_n \sigma A_n= A_n=\sigma A_n A_n$, hence your group is abelian. So regardless of what is the identity element your group is always abelian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n=1,$ then the result follows trivially. So let $n\geq 2.$ Since order of $S_n/A_n$ is $2$ which is prime and any group of prime order is cyclic, therefore $S_n/A_n$ is cyclic and hence also abelian.

Comment: (To correct the trivial case, $n>1$.)

Comment: Ah! I almost forgot the trivial case. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

You know that the order of $S_n/A_n$ is two (for $n\ge 2$; it is trivial (and hence abelian) otherwise). There is only one group of order two up to isomorphism: $\Bbb Z_2$. (One way to see this is to construct a Cayley table.) But $\Bbb Z_2$ is cyclic and hence abelian.

---

Another proof, somewhat overkill, is to use the First Isomorphism Theorem, with

$$\begin{align}
\varphi: S_n&\to (\{1,-1\},\times),\\
\rho &\mapsto {\rm sgn}(\rho).
\end{align}$$

I will leave this as an exercise.

---

One could argue that the second proof above is what goes on behind the scenes of the first proof.

Answer (score 0):

To show that / is commutative, you need to show that = for all ∉. This is equivalent to showing that ()2=, which means that  is an element of order 2 in /.

Since  is an element of  that is not in , it can be written as a product of an odd number of 2-cycles. You can write  as a product of 2-cycles in the following way:

= (11)(22) ... ()

where  and  are elements of {1, 2, ..., }.

Since  is an odd permutation,  is odd. We can rewrite  as follows:

= (11)(22) ... ()

Since  is the group of even permutations, and each 2-cycle is an even permutation, we can simplify the expression to:

= (11)(22) ... ()
Since  is odd, the expression  is equal to . Therefore, =.

Now we can show that ()2=:

()2 =  =  = 2 =

Since ()2=,  is an element of order 2 in /. This means that / is an abelian group, and therefore / is commutative.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Please format your math using MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).